# Ingesting decimal in hive table of Avro Serde

Tags: hive, binary, decimal, avro

I am trying to check whether i can change the precision and scale of decimal field in hive with Avro Serde.So I have writtenbelow code.

```
create database test_avro;
use test_avro_table;
create external table test_table(
  name string,
  salary decimal(17,2),
  country string
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ","
STORED AS textfile;


LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/appsdesdssu/data/CACS_POC/data/' INTO TABLE 
test_table;

create external table test_table_avro
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
tblproperties ('avro.schema.literal'='{
"name": "my_record",
"type": "record",
"fields": [
 {"name":"name", "type":"string"},
 {"name":"salary","type": "bytes","logicalType": "decimal","precision": 
 17,"scale": 2},
 {"name":"country", "type":"string"}
 ]}');

 insert overwrite table test_table_avro  select * from test_table;
```

Here, I am getting error saying

```
FAILED: UDFArgumentException Only string, char, varchar or binary data can be cast into binary data types.
```

Data file:

```
steve,976475632987465.257,USA
rogers,349643905318384.137,mexico
groot,534563663653653.896,titan
```

If i am missing anything here than please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hive did not support decimal to Binary version till now. So we have to work around by first converting it to string and than binary.So, below lines

```
 insert overwrite table test_table_avro  select * from test_table;
```

needs change to

```
 insert overwrite table test_table_avro  select name,cast(cast(salary as string) as binary),country from test_table;
```